# Why are Class E IPs in use?

Tags: ipv4

According to all documentation, class E IPs - those in the range 240.0.0.0 to 255.255.255.255 - are for research purposes only and should never be assigned or used.  And yet, according to a review of access logs in a site I run, upwards of 70% of visits are coming from IPs in this "forbidden" range.  Some tools break when applied to IPs in this range, so I am a bit concerned.

I was able to send private messages to a few users.  Of those who responded, they disclaimed any knowledge of what could be going on.  Both American and European users were affected, and they claimed both hardwired connections and mobile connections.

So, this is a situation where the behavior defined in the formal document and the behavior exhibited in the real world differ.  What does it mean to be seeing a lot of traffic from these 'forbidden' IPs?

Comment: fit your question, so it can be answered. currently it's like you hang on documentation that is now 40 years old.

Comment: Where exactly are you seeing these addresses? Can it be that your local hosting company is doing something weird, because these addresses indeed aren’t used on the internet.

Answer (score 3):

To probably explain the down votes :

*Class E IP  ranges* do not exist any more.

Classfull network addressing is an **obsolete** network addressing architecture that was used in the Internet from 1981 until the introduction of Classless Inter-Domain Routing (CIDR) in **1993**.

Those IP ranges are currently classified as `Reserved for future use (formerly "Class E")` : source https://www.iana.org/assignments/ipv4-address-space/ipv4-address-space.xhtml

No explanation as to why you see them in the wild.

Comment: Please reread the question.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

They might be IPv6 users and I guess you are using Cloudflare proxy to serve your website. According to the Cloudflare documentation, Cloudflare uses Class E IP space to generate Pseudo IPv4 addresses when somebody access to the origin by using IPv6.

https://blog.cloudflare.com/eliminating-the-last-reasons-to-not-enable-ipv6/

Comment: Unfortunately, not using a proxy, but thank you for your insight.